# Liferay mvn build-css & sass @charset pasted into @import ? : @charset may only be used at the root of a document

Tags: maven, sass, liferay-theme, liferay-6.2

Liferay 6.2
Maven 3.3.9

I'm using liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.10.13:build-css to compile scss files to css.

my main.css is :

```
@import url(base.css);
@import url(application.css);
@import url(layout.css);
@import url(dockbar.css);
@import url(navigation.css);
@import url(portlet.css);
@import url(extras.css);
@import url(custom.css);
@import "wip/main";
```

which is a normal Liferay main.css file. I just added the wip/main import (which is a scss file).

My wip/main.scss file is :

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/////////////////////////////
// variables
@import "app-var";
@import "app-mixins";

/////////////////////////////
// maincontent
@import "slider-banner";
@import "membership-box";
// more @imports...
```

And it works ! Great :)

Now I want to prefix all my wip/main.scss rules (which are imported from different files) with a :

```
.aui {
```

So something like :

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.aui {
    /////////////////////////////
    // variables
    @import "app-var";
    @import "app-mixins";
    // maincontent
    @import "slider-banner";
    @import "membership-box";
}
```

But then I've got the exception :

```
Failed to execute goal com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.10.13:build-css (default) on project wip-theme: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: (SyntaxError) @charset may only be used at the root of a document. -> [Help 1]
```

So just adding `.aui {` - AFTER - the `@charset "UTF-8";` crashes the build.

I bet `@charset` is copied to all `@import` files and thus `.aui {` is containing a `@charset`... but I don't know if this is the problem, and how to avoid it.

Anyone knows a workaround ? Thanks

Comment: Does it work with no charset in the main file and with charsets in each partials?

Comment: No. with my main.css having no charset and a partial using @Charset, I've got the same error (as main.css is encapsulating my partials imports in another class)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the @charset from my scss files and setting directly the file encoding through my IDE.

So far so good.

Btw it seems it is a maven problem (configuration or so) as doing the same with grunt (grunt build) won't cause any problems.

Anyway working under maven if I remove the @charset. Not the best, but until finding better...